# Why am I getting this error in Concourse? Error: No step configured

Tags: continuous-integration, concourse, concourse-pipeline

I am brand new to concourse and am trying to use it to make a terraform-ci platform and cannot figure out why im getting this error on my very first pipeline, can anyone help out?

```
jobs:
  - name: terraform-pipeline
    serial: true
    plan:
      - aggregate:
        - get: master-branch
          trigger: true 
        - get: common-tasks
          params: { submodules: [ terraform ] }
          trigger: true
      - task: terraform-plan
        file: common-tasks/terraform/0.12.29.yml
        input_mapping: { source: master-branch }
        params:
          command: plan
          cache: true
          access_key: ((aws-access-key))
          secret_key: ((aws-secret-key))
          directory: master-branch/terraform-poc/dev
          
resources:
  - name: master-branch
    type: git
    source:
      uri: https://github.com/rossrollin/terraform-poc
      branch: master
  - name: common-tasks
    type: git
    source:
      uri: https://github.com/telia-oss/concourse-tasks.git
      branch: master
```

Executing pipeline like so:

```
fly -t concourse-poc sp -p terraform-pipeline -c pipeline2.yml -v aws-access-key=''-v aws-secret-key=''
error: error unmarshaling JSON: while decoding JSON: no step configured
```

Comment: Which version of Concourse are you running?

Answer (score 1):

The `aggregate` step was deprecated in version 5.2.0 and removed in version [7.0.0](https://github.com/concourse/concourse/releases#6349).

You need to replace it with the new [in_parallel](https://concourse-ci.org/jobs.html#in-parallel-step) step.

```
-      - aggregate:
+      - in_parallel:
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing '- aggregate:' and just running the resource get's inline fixes my issue.